# How to detect if game object out of overlapsphere range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a range to shoot for a gameobject. It detects when a gameobject joins range but not detects gameobject outs range.If its possible i want to know how detect if enemy outs range. Thanks for any helps.

> Example code for detect enemy.

```
Collider[] hitNpcs = Physics.OverlapSphere(TowerPoint.transform.position, Range);

    for (int i = 0; i < hitNpcs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hitNpcs[i].GetComponent<Npc>() != null)
        {
             hitNpcs[i].GetComponent<NpcHP>().dmg(Power);
             Debug.Log("Shoot");
             break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to other npcs? Not only the one that are colliding?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while an interesting question for absolute beginners, there are literally 100s of pages that very clearly explain this basic point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note***: this assumes that your Npc has a `RigidBody` component attached.

Instead of using `Physics.OverlapShere`, create a spherical collider on your `TowerPoint` GameObject, and you can then use the [`OnCollisionExit`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html) method to detect npcs leaving the range.